# Get every n record from database - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grid

I am trying to make a responsive image grid (here is an example from w3schools: [Responsive Image Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_grid_responsive)). From the example, they have the following `html`:

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/falls2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/ocean.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" style="width:100%">
    ...
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/falls2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/ocean.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" style="width:100%">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

However, they are using static content. I want to make the content dynamic. I've done some research and found the following solution: [Return every nth row from database using ActiveRecord in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250738/return-every-nth-row-from-database-using-activerecord-in-rails). Not sure if this is the right way, but my goal is to put every `n` element in each `column` without specifying the limit.

Currently, I have the following code in my controller:

```
def index
  @photos = Photos.is_active.all
end
```

Index view:

```
= render partial: "photos", collection: @photos
```

Is there any right way to implement the solution from w3school and make a dynamic content with Ruby on Rails loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`in_groups_of`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of) does exactly what you're looking for.

*Splits or iterates over the array in groups of size `number`, padding
any remaining slots with `fill_with` unless it is `false`.*

```
%w(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10).in_groups_of(3) {|group| p group}
["1", "2", "3"]
["4", "5", "6"]
["7", "8", "9"]
["10", nil, nil]

%w(1 2 3 4 5).in_groups_of(2, '&nbsp;') {|group| p group}
["1", "2"]
["3", "4"]
["5", "&nbsp;"]

%w(1 2 3 4 5).in_groups_of(2, false) {|group| p group}
["1", "2"]
["3", "4"]
["5"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Editing the original question. I would propose:

Each_slice: https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice