# ActiveRecord query for all of last day's data and every 100th record prior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a process that generates a new record every 10 minutes. It was great for some time, however, now `Datum.all` returns 30k+ records, which are unnecessary as the purpose is simply to display them on a chart.

So as a simple solution, I'd like to provide all available data generated in the past 24 hours, but low res data (every 100th record) prior to the last 24 hours (right back to the beginning of the dataset).

I suspect the solution is some combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3147663/5783745) answer which selects every nth record (but was provided in 2010), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9540911/5783745) answer which combines two ActiveRecord objects

But I cannot work out how to get a working implementation that obtains all the required data into one instance variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OR` query:

```
Datum.where("created_at>?", 1.day.ago).or(Datum.where("id%100=0"))
```

Comment: This is so elegant and worked immediately. Much appreciated